# No razor syntax coloring/Unable to set breakpoints in razor Visual Studio 2013 Preview

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2013, resharper-8.0

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2013 preview a long with the ASP.NET and Web Tools for Visual Studio 2013 update. I have also got ReSharper 8.0 installed with it.

Since installing it, and opening an Umbraco project which was created in Visual Studio 2012, all my razor syntax colouring has disappeared, and I am also unable to set breakpoints in the razor code. When I try and set a breakpoint I get this message:

"A breakpoint could not be inserted at this location"

I have searched all over the internet for similar issues, but I can't seem to find a definitive reason or solution. The only lead I have found is in the comments on Scott Gu's  blog, on his post about MVC3 RC, and in the comments it says that ReSharper can sometimes interfere with Visual studio syntax colouring etc.

I have tried the suggestions (reverting back to VS intellisense/code hinting etc) but I still have no syntax colouring on razor, and I still cannot set breakpoints in razor either.

As I said previously, the project was created in Visual Studio 2012 with ReSharper 7.1 installed and all the VS updates installed, and these problems did not exist.

Has anyone had this issue before? For any version of VS?

Thanks.

Comment: I have this issue as well with a clean Visual Studio 2013 (Release) install.

Answer (score 0):

Previously had issues with this as well (although syntax highlighting wasn't a problem, but debugging was).

Go here for an update on debugging issues:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807088/unable-to-debug-javascript-from-the-vs-2013-ide-unable-to-set-breakpoint#tabs

VS 2013 Update 2 seems to have resolved it for me.